# Uploading Database to SQL With Python

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I am working on a SQL project that involves making edits to the Database with Python.

I have had no problem connecting to the server to download the information into Pandas with this

```
ca_cannabis = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=LAPTOP-E6QKON1L;'
                      'Database=ca_cannabis;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
```

but after I have made the changes and am trying to send the information back to SQL, I keep running into problems.

Instructions I have found have told me to create an engine through SQLAlchemy

```
engine = create_engine("mssql+pymssql://LAPTOP-E6QKON1L/ca_cannabis")
```

and

```
ca_roll_final.to_sql(
            name='ca_roll_test',
            con=engine.connect(),
            if_exists='append',
            index=False
                    )
```

which I have tweaked around by swapping pyodbc and pymssql, putting in my username, adding .format() to add info similar to the ca_cannabis file, but they all keep getting different erros, like no default driver given or no server name.

Anyone got any tips for making this work?

I use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18, if that matters.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) should include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it *as formatted text* **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mre].

Comment: Please don't post the same question repeatedly. If you are not getting any answers to a question then edit it to improve it.